# How to get post slug from post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get "abc_15_11_02_3" from http://example.com/project_name/abc_15_11_02_3/. How can i do this?

Answer (score 91):

You can get that using the following methods:

```
<?php $post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ); ?>
```

Or You can use this easy code:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
?>
```

Comment: $post->post_name as its name suggests, returns post name(title) not slug

Comment: @ArtinGH Your comment is wrong, post_name is indeed the slug and NOT the post title.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to get slug of the post **from the loop** then use:

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_name;
```

---

If you want to get slug of the post **outside the loop** then use:

```
$post_id = 45; //specify post id here
$post = get_post($post_id); 
$slug = $post->post_name;
```

Answer (score 22):

You can do this is in many ways like:

1- You can use Wordpress global variable `$post` :

```
<?php 
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;
?>
```

2- Or you can get use:

```
$slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
```

3- Or get full url and then use the PHP function `parse_url`:

```
$url      = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url_path = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );
$slug = pathinfo( $url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
```

I hope above methods will help you.

Answer (score 13):

this simple code worked for me:

```
$postId = get_the_ID();
$slug = basename(get_permalink($postId));
echo $slug;
```

Answer (score 12):

Best option to do this according to WP Codex is as follow.

Use the global variable $post:

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Wordpress: Get post/page slug

```
<?php 
// Custom function to return the post slug
function the_slug($echo=true){
  $slug = basename(get_permalink());
  do_action('before_slug', $slug);
  $slug = apply_filters('slug_filter', $slug);
  if( $echo ) echo $slug;
  do_action('after_slug', $slug);
  return $slug;
}
?>
<?php if (function_exists('the_slug')) { the_slug(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve it from the post object like so:

```
global $post;
$post->post_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Current Post object.**

```
global $post;
$slug = $post->post_name;
```

**Other Options:**

Any Post using ID.

```
$post = get_post($post_id);
$slug = $post->post_name;
```

In the loop

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name' );
}
```

Outside the loop using ID

```
$page_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id );
```

Answer (score 2):

use global variable $post

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is most advanced and updated version what cover many cases:

```
if(!function_exists('the_slug')):
    function the_slug($post_id=false, $echo=true) {
        global $product, $page;

        if(is_numeric($post_id) && $post_id == intval($post_id)) {} else {
            if(!is_object($post_id)){}else if(property_exists($post_id, 'ID')){
                $post_id = $post_id->ID;
            }
            if(empty($post_id) && property_exists($product, 'ID')) $post_id = $product->ID;
            if(empty($post_id)) $post_id =  get_the_ID();

            if(empty($post_id) && property_exists($page, 'ID')) $post_id =  $page->ID;
        }

        if(!empty($post_id))
            $slug = basename(get_permalink($post_id));
        else
            $slug = basename(get_permalink());
        do_action('before_slug', $slug);
        $slug = apply_filters('slug_filter', $slug);
        if( $echo ) echo $slug;
        do_action('after_slug', $slug);
        return $slug;
      }
endif;
```

This is collections from the best answers and few my updates.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this method and I use it to make div IDs the slug name inside the loop:

```
<?php $slug = basename( get_permalink() ); echo $slug;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_postype',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        global $post;
        $post_slug=$post->post_name;
        echo $post_slug;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).