# Encode the url including hyphen in php

Tags: php, wordpress, urlencode

I have the following URL: http://test.com/client/!MG2s-/

I want to be able to grab the slug and use it further down in my code

With the following code:

`$page_slug=$post->post_name;
echo $page_slug;`

the output is `!mg2s`

Even if the url is http://test.com/client/%21MG2s%2D/ the result is still the same. The slug is generated from a third party app, so the hyphen is required. I understand that dashes are used to sanitize titles, but I need to find a way to display the hyphen.

I have also tried with no success:

`$page_slug= urlencode($post->post_name);
$str = str_replace('-', '%2D', $page_slug);
echo $str;`

Is there any way that the hyphen can be displayed?

**FURTHER NOTE:** This is only happening to slugs ending with hyphens. Slugs with hyphens in between have no issues displaying the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842251/how-to-get-post-slug-from-post-in-wordpress/33842293#33842293)

```
$url="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url_path=parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );
$page_slug=pathinfo( $url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
```

instead of using

```
$page_slug=$post->post_name;
```