# PHP get_permalink wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

get permalink in PHP, but not full, so that what I need is `www.example.com/OnlyThisPartoffParmalink`

that what I want to do is example link `https://www.imdb.com/title/HERE I WANT THE WORDPRS PARMALINK/` no WordPress id.

I have to make a post like this `www.mywebsite.com/tt5846644/` etc.. and this tt5846644 different in every post, and I want to add this with php https://www.imdb.com/title`/<?php I need the code here ?>/` to get in automatic this `tt5846644` from every post link?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of several questions on wordpress.stackexchange.com. eg

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32728/get-page-permalink-without-wpurl

Comment: thanks, can you help me how to add that code  here '<span class="imdbRatingPlugin" data-title="<?php echo esc_url ?>" data-style="p1"><a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/.'<?php echo esc_url ?>'./"><img src="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/images/imdb_46x22.png" /> '

Comment: See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237872

Comment: thanks, but still i need help how to add that php code here  data-title=" HERE "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33842251/3739498 - You're looking for the slug, not the permalink. You can also use `$slug = basename(get_permalink());` then your `<?php echo $slug?>` will work where you need to output it.

Comment: Thanks man this is working thanks